# Impact on MySQL SELECT query if we search a string with length greater than column's length

Tags: mysql

I have a column field **"name"** with **type VARCHAR** and **length** as 80 .
If i search for a string with length greater than 80 , what is the behaviour of SELECT operation in this case ?

Apart from round trip to DB , will it scan whole table or just perform a return as the length is already greater than 80 ?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE name = "longgg... ...string" ;
```

I need this knowledge because in the existing codebase there is a variable which is used in all layers of MVC . This variable is meant for a different column with different length . For saving time and code redundancy I just want to use same variable which has validation for a bigger length as compared to 80.

> After the discussion , I am going to add length validation instead of
>   depending on db validation as all the rows are scanned !

One more wise thought in the comments , if the column is indexed whole table is not scanned .Verified same using EXPLAIN  :

> All rows are scanned as there is no index. CHAR/VARCHAR index stores length as well (included in explain/key_len). So if index created on the column, the query should not compare anything as based by the index SQL should understand that there is no rows found by criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a documentation reference for this, but from my observations testing what will happen is that MySQL will cast both sides of the equality expression to the length of the string literal on the RHS.  That is, MySQL will execute the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST(name AS CHAR(100)) = CAST('longgg... ...string' AS CHAR(100));
-- assuming it has a length of 100
```

This comparison would generally fail, since MySQL will not pad a string on the LHS which is less than 100 characters, meaning that the lengths would not generally even match.

Comment: @Nick I tested the other possibility, namely that MySQL casts both sides to the width of the `name` column (80).  It doesn't seem to be doing this, because then comparing to an RHS whose first 80 characters match should return a record, but this doesn't happen.  No doc reference though, but I am pretty sure that some sort of casting much be happening here.

Comment: Agreed, it's just your query didn't match the words you were using. I see you've edited so I'll delete...

Comment: but this still doesnt give any clue about whether table scan is happening because even the lhs is casted as CHAR(100) in this case . Please correct me if i am not right

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy I ran `EXPLAIN` here on some local test data, and it reports that MySQL is doing a full table scan.  Not sure what would happen with your actual data.

Comment: can you paste yours EXPLAIN result as well .

Comment: [Check the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa9a043e49ed2e0c5df67cad0ed8734c)

Comment: If the column indexed, the index should be used. As your string in query is longer than any value in table, MySQL will just compare the 'length' part of the index that should be quite fast.

Comment: @fifonik , if you check the comment by Tim where he has shared the link for explain query ,  it turns out all the rows are scanned  .

Comment: @DivyanshuJimmy Yes... _but_ I don't have indices setup in the demo.  Fonik is suggesting that if an index were present, then MySQL might just scan that index and only have to check the length.

Comment: All rows are scanned as there is no index. CHAR/VARCHAR index stores length as well (included in explain/key_len). So if index created on the column, the query should not compare anything as based by the index SQL should understand that there is no rows found by criteria. I might be wrong as I have not checked code.

Comment: @fifonik , i verified it by doing a test .You and Tim are right . this was very helpful .